# Data fetching from database with different ids using pipe sign

Tags: php, mysql

I've ids in database separated with pipe sign like.

```
13|14|15|16|17|18
```

but the problem is the value in that field can be only `13` if the value is double it'll be separated by pipe sign like `13|14` but also it can be null/empty field, now all of these ids have parent and it is `12` so I used `WHERE levelParent = '12'` in my query so if the value exists in field it fetch data and show me if the value is null it didn't show me the data although the data belongs to that category so how to fix it in my query.

query is

```
SELECT u.userId, u.userCompanyName, u.userLevel, IF(CONCAT(u.userCompanyCity,', ',u.userCompanyCountry) != '', CONCAT(u.userCompanyCity,', ',u.userCompanyCountry), 'Location not defined') AS location, u.userCompanyPhone, u.userEmail, IF(userStatus = 1, 1, 0) AS userStatus FROM mje_user u INNER JOIN mje_user_level ul ON (u.userLevel = ul.levelId) WHERE ul.levelParent = '12' AND u.userStatus = '1' ORDER BY u.userCompanyName ASC
```

Comment: post the whole query.

Comment: When will people learn that a failure to normalize their data tables is guaranteed to cause them problems like this

Comment: Show the table definition. Why are you storing multiple values in one column?

Comment: Any one can help me in this query without changing the query.